# quartzjob wont let me start service?

Tags: service

I seem to unable to start a service, the error log reports that is cannot be started

```
 inRiver Server
 Version: 6.3.0
 Copyright © inRiver 2017
______________________________________________

15:17:15 - Information   Initialized Loggers
15:17:15 - Information   Verifying database access
15:17:15 - Information   QuartzJobs: Stopping job scheduler
15:17:15 - Information   Server has been stopped
```

Any idea of what kind of quartz job is messing with me here?
And how do fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your standpoint Im guessing you are running the 6.3 SP3 version?
In your server config. can you extend your logging level to show errors aswell?

But just to give you some more information when Quartz job is failing at startup it's a fallback plan when something is wrong when starting the server.

So its hard to give you a guess on what it can be but see if there are some information in StartupError.txt or as I said, extend the log-level to get more info.

Get back on your findings and I will see if I can help you some more.

Edit: After some thinking I believe this happens for you because the server is trying to verify the database access and it wont succeed. And therefor it throws exception and the fallback looks like the error is because of Quartz but it isn't